# Delete record error with custom method model laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

User model

```
public function take($id){
    return $this->find($id);
}

public function kill(){
    return $this->delete();
}
```

Route Error 1

```
Route::get('delete/{userid}', function($id)
{

    $user = new User;
    $user->take($id); //result the content of $id
    $user->kill();
});
```

i can't delete record with these route and only show blank page (without error).

Route errror 2

```
Route::get('delete/{userid}', function($id)
{
    User::take($id)->kill();
});
```

And with above route i get error Non-static method User::take() should not be called statically

But i can delete with this route

```
Route::get('show/{userid}', function($id)
{
    $user = new User;
    $user->take($id)->kill();
});
```

1. So how to fix Route error 1, if i want to use $user-> without chain take() and kill() ? if it possible
2. How to fix Route error 2, if i want to use **User::** , and why these error happen ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below :

```
  Route::get('show/{$id}', function($id)
    {
     $user = new User;
     $user->find($id)->kill();
    });
```

I think the param accepted has to have the same things that is passed to the closure.

Comment: i want to use my custom method take($id) instead of find() and without chaining find() and kill() , if it possible.

Comment: nevermind take() to take how much record you want , and find() to find ID.
thanks a lot bro i should us as is.